# VuetifyTypescript project build failed in netlify

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs2, build, netlify

I have vue2 and vuetify project written using typescript. Following is configuration files.

`package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
  },
```

Now, When I try to build using command `yarn run build`, it successfully builds the dist folder but build fails in production (netlify).

While deploying in netlify, it throws following error

```
8:21:26 PM: gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
8:21:26 PM: gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
8:21:26 PM: gyp ERR! not ok
8:21:26 PM: Build failed with error code: 1
8:21:26 PM: Error during Yarn install
8:21:26 PM: Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
8:21:26 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
8:21:26 PM: Finished processing build request in 2m47.929466659s
```